# Why does PowerPoint prints in wrong colors?

Tags: windows, printing, colors, powerpoint, foxpro

We have lots of Windows 7 Professional workstations. We have a specific program that has been developed with Visual FoxPro that produces 32 bit applications that is deployed to many workstations.

On just one of these workstations when we print images from out of that specific application the colors are wrong, especially yellow turns to blue. In the same application but from another part of it images can be printed without any problems or failures with correct colors.

On the same PC I can print the same image file by other applications (Word, IrfanView, etc.) and the colors look correct.

So to wrap things up: Printing from a specific procedure in the FoxPro application produces images with yellow color turned to blue. All other prints from other parts of the FoxPro application and all other programs on that PC look good.

Any idea what could be the reason for this issue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Printer driver looks suspicious.

Comment: The same printer driver is installed on that PC like all other PCs. To make sure it is not printer driver related I re-installed the printer driver. It didn't help!

Comment: Instead of reinstalling that driver I would try removing that diver and printing to file and\or use a driver that ships with win. Also it maybe related to gdiplus.dll on that machine. In worst case, I would try capturing raw bytes sent to printer and compare with the ones that work (do not have an idea how would I do that at this moment, I would search if it happened to me).

Comment: Thanks! I could print a screenshot using the Win programm Paint. Colors were OK. In the printer driver I set the "ICM Method" to "ICM Handled by Printer". In that case the yellow color was correct but only 10% of the image height was printed. Maybe this information gives you a clue!!

Comment: No further ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual FoxPro is an old development environment that produces old-style application code. Such applications get display and printing problems if the general windows display appearance is not set to 100%. In this case it was set to 125%.

I set the display appearance back to 100% and rebooted. Then I printed the same image and colors were printed correctly.